# Chart changes different on zoom when using multiple charts with chart.js and flask

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js

For some reason on scroll wheel zoom my charts are replaced by only one chart.

First I create a canvas for each chart using flask

```
        <div height=50% id="chartcanvas">
            <canvas id="{{site}}canvas" ></canvas>

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Then I loop through each canvas and assign a chart to it. I basically recolor each chart to highlight a certain site.It works find when the page loads, but when you try to interact or zoom on a chart it replaces the data with only one of the charts (the first in the list)

```
data_all = ...//initial variable with data

    {% for site in sites %}
    
    var {{site}}data=data_all
    i=1
    for (s of {{site}}data){
    if (s.label == '{{site}}'){
        s.borderColor='#0000ff'
        s.order=0
        } else {
        s.borderColor='rgba(166,166,166,0.2)'}
        s.order=i
    i++
    };
    


        
        var {{site}}ctx = document.getElementById('{{site}}canvas').getContext('2d');
        var {{site}} = new Chart({{site}}ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: { datasets: {{site}}data },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            
            
            zoom: {
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: 'x'
                },
            pan: {
              enabled: true,
              mode: 'xy'
                },
              

            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                type: 'time'
              }]
            },
            
          }
        });
        
    

    
    {% endfor %}
```

I also am loading these versions of chart.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.0"></script>
```

Comment: I looked at this and it does not solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626610/multiple-chart-on-one-page-using-chart-js-and-flask-app

Comment: Did you try updating to the lastest version of zoom (0.7.7) for chartjs v2 since this version came out a year after the version in your snippet the issue might have been solved.

Comment: I just tried that and get the same error, but I will leave it on the latest version.

Comment: Also, it is any time the chart is redrawn, not just on zoom. If I resize the window it also replaces all of the charts.

Answer (score 0):

One option that does fix the problem is to disable zoom. Now I have no zoom... I also determined that the problem is any time the plot is redrawn, such as resizing the window.